# PostgreSQL: Combining delete and update

Tags: sql, postgresql

Problem: set of spreadsheets that need to be parsed into a postgres database. Inserting is straigth forward. But what if the data in the spread sheet changes.

So a python3 scripts reads the spread sheet which is a mix of variables (sheet1) and raw time series(sheet2). Spreadsheets are flexibel for the data collection, that is why.

However I seem to stumble with changing data in the spread sheet. I'm using postgresql 9.6, and I know how to do UPSERT.

One of the tables looks like this:
| id | key_to_other_table | parameter | value|

UPSERT works perfect when the key_to_other_table and parameter is or isn't in the table.

The problem is when a parameter originally was in the spreadsheet and uploaded to the database, but was corrected in the spreadsheet, but is still in the database.

I need to do some kind of delete, but I don't want to do a blunt delete of all rows and then simply re-insert as I use the id...

I would now do a fetch, getting all id of the row linked to a certain spreadsheet, do an upsert of the values, and get id of that.

Compare the two list and then delete the ones that are no longer needed.
But this seems like three different database queries... 
Is there an elegant way of doing this in a single step?

Comment: What is your unique key for this working upsert?

Comment: This sounds like a big mess to me.  I would advise you against working with spreadsheets if you have requirements for fine/precise control of your data.  Postgres is a good place to host your data though.

Comment: Any other suggestion is welcome, but working with spreadsheets is a compromise between usability for the operators and the datastructure I want. The spreadsheet are structured and are template based.

Answer (score 0):

If you extend the table in with some sort of "load identifier" and populate that with the UPSERT, you can then delete any records from the table that do not have the load identifier you're expecting.

General flow:

1. ThisLoadIdentifier := current timestamp
2. upsert the rows from the spreadsheet, set load_identifier = ThisLoadIdentifier
3. delete from table where load_identifier != ThisLoadIdentifier

Sample Walkthrough:

**Initial Setup**.

Extend your table to add `load_id` of type `varchar` column.

`ALTER TABLE myTable ADD load_id VARCHAR;`

`| id | key_to_other_table | parameter | value | load_id |`

Update all the existing rows to have an initial value.

```
`UPDATE myTable SET load_id = 'Existing Records';`
```

**Loading**

1. Change your python script so that before it starts doing the load, it comes up with a unique load_id.   Something like the current time etc.

   `this_load_id = time.ctime()`
2. In your insert/upsert populate the `load_id` column with your new `this_load_id` value.
3. Once the load has completed.   Every row that you inserted or updated will have the `load_id = this_load_id`.
   Any row where `load_id` does not have this value is from an older load and wasn't in this spreadsheet.
   You can then get rid of them with a simple delete

   `delete from myTable where load_id != this_load_id`

Caveat: You'd probably want to use something more efficient than a time/date string in production.

Comment: auch, my brain just popped. Would you have some kind of example or web tutorial/example? i'm following completly

Comment: @llpepe4 I've added more detail.